# Два идущих подряд глагола

Tags: запятая

Словосочетание "давай ешь": ставить ли запятую между ними?

Answer (score 6):

Согласна с behemothus. Давай - формообразующая частица. Она образует форму повелительного наклонения. Запятая не нужна.

Comment: Без контекста, просто повелительная конструкция "давай ешь" - пишется без запятой. Я позволил себе ширше осветить вопрос. А так, конечно... Кстати, и без частицы *давай* повелительное наклонение глаголов отлично существует.
>Ешь ананасы, рябчиков жуй...

*Давай, ешь свои буржуйские ананасы.*

Улавливаете разницу.

Answer (score 5):

В предложениях с этим словосочетанием (*давай ешь*) встречаются и другие слова. Так что возможны варианты, в зависимости от авторской интонации.

Давай, ешь скорее.

Ну давай, ешь меня с потрохами.

Ты давай ешь!

В этих примерах *давай* - частица, побуждающая к действию, а не глагол.

Как я думаю, частица *давай* может принимать на себя значение вводного слова (см. выше 1 и 2 пример); соответственно интонации она выделяется запятой (запятыми). По крайней мере, с другими "глагольными" частицами такое отмечено в [справочниках](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1689-1705.html) :

> Частицы **бывало, бывает** близки к вводным словам; они обозначают нерегулярную повторяемость...

Другие ресурсы прямо называют слова *бывает, бывало* - вводными. Нет в таком случае никаких препятствий считать в определенных случаях частицу *давай* вводным словом.

> Дина Рубина. Белая голубка Кордовы (2008-2009) Ну, давай, начинай, я слушаю. Будешь моей Шехерезадой: пока длится сказка, девушка живет. (Нацкорпус)

Comment: *Давай* и *бывало* - совершенно разные звери. Как одно можно обосновывать аналогией с другим - ума не приложу.

Comment: Это "отглагольные" частицы, так шта не стоит так громко удивляться!
Все русские правила построены на аналогиях, сопоставлениях, сближениях, прецедентах, узусах, сложившейся практике, редакторских предпочтениях, авторском видении etc.

Comment: Бывает - не частица.

Comment: Я указал ссылку, см. выше (Инсти[тут](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1689-1705.html) русского языка)
>§ 1694. К частицам, характеризующим признак (действие или состояние) по его протеканию во времени, по полноте или неполноте осуществления, по результативности или нерезультативности, относятся **частицы было, бывало, бывает**...

Comment: Тем не менее "бывает" не признают за частицу современные авторы. 
Сомнения уже в том, что "бывает" - как обычное вводное слово требует обособления и на значении глагола не сказывается. В то время как "было" действительно модифицирует значение. Хотя в редких случаях и оно модет быть вводным.   
Смею напомнить, что АГ - тридцать лет, а теория частиц претерпела сильные изменения за как раз за последние 20-30 лет.В серелине семидесятых о частицах как частях речи обычно только упоминали.

Answer (score 2):

*Давай* здесь может быть не глаголом, а частицей. Если частица, то запятая, естественно,  не нужна.

А если глагол, т.е. имеется в  виду два действия (давай и ешь), то нужна.

Скорее всего здесь именно частица, поэтому - без запятой.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от смысла. Если идёт перечисление действий, то запятая ставится, если перечисления нет - не ставится, так как тут составное сказуемое. Для проверки можно поставить между глаголами восклицательный знак, и если смысл фразы изменился, то запятая не ставится.