# Нужна ли запятая после "давай"?

Tags: пунктуация

Все время мучаюсь в терзаниях, встречая такие предложения)) Нужна ли запятая после "давай"?

*Давай быстрее собирайся.*

*Ну давай проходи уже.*

*Ты давай не заводись.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре Ефремовой:
[дава́й](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/274330/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9) — *част. разг.*; = дава́йте
1. Употребляется при выражении побуждения, призыва кого-либо к какому-либо действию.
2. Употребляется при выражении приказа совершить какое-либо действие.
3. Употребляется при выражении одобрения чего-либо, согласия с чем-либо, соответствуя по значению словам: *хорошо, ладно, пусть будет так.*
4. Употребляется при выражении готовности совместно с кем-либо совершить какое-либо действие.

В словаре Кузнецова:
[дава́й(те)](https://www.endic.ru/kuzhecov/Davat-2718.html), *в зн. частицы.* (с инф. *нсв.* или с 1 л. *мн. ч.* буд. вр.). *Разг.*
1. Выражает приглашение к совместному действию или побуждение к действию. *Давай мириться! Давайте посидим, отдохнём, покурим. Спи давай! Давайте поторапливайтесь. Давай отсюда!* (*грубо*; убирайся). *Давайте все по домам* (расходись, разбегайся). *Давай бог ноги* (о быстром, поспешном бегстве).

В каждом конкретном предложении пунктуация может быть вариативной — все зависит от контекста и того смысла, который Вы хотите передать.

Быстрее собирайся! = Давай быстрее собирайся! [частица относится к двум словам]
Быстрее, собирайся. = Давай быстрее, собирайся. [частица относится только к одному слову]

Сравните (О. Владимирова. Другой мир. Другая жизнь):
***Давай уже одевайся***, нам надо бежать!
Я тоже рада тебя видеть, но **давай поторопимся!**
**Давай быстрее собирайся!** А то мы точно опоздаем!

***— Давай быстрее, собирайся***, — бледная Юлька кинулась в ванну (Л. Савельев. Мясо по-французски).

Рассуждения и примеры есть и в дискуссии на нашем сайте (***давай ешь***):
[Два идущих подряд глагола](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21795/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3):

В ваших примерах "давай" употреблено в качестве частицы. Запятые не нужны.

Бывают случаи, когда запятую нужно поставить и после "ну" (это междометие в данном случае, и после "давай" в значении "ладно, хорошо, действуй" перед глаголом повелительного наклонения, если присутствует разделительная интонация, как при однородных членах:

***Ну, давай, пробуй. ― Да уж дождись товарища-то, ― сказал он, встал и быстро пошёл от костра в сторону деревни.*** [Юрий Коваль. Ножевик (1990)]

Интонационную самостоятельность приобретает этикетное междометие "давай" в значении "пока, до свидания":

***Думаю, те и самой лишние проблемы без надобности. Ну, давай. До свидания… Ага.*** [Марина Палей. Дань саламандре (2008)]

О слове "давай" есть материал [здесь](https://pishugramotno.ru/punktuacia/davaj-zapyataya-posle-slova-nuzhna-ili-net)

Примеры взяла из Нацкорпуса.

Answer (score 0):

В приложенных приложениях будет стоять запятая, потому что вы обращаетесь к человеку. Происходит обращение к персоне. 
Давай, быстрее собирайся.
Вы сказали человеку собираться быстрее, а значит обратились к нему. Также можно обращаться по имени с человеком, всё равно запятая остаётся на своём месте. Только теперь и перед словом будет стоять запятая. 
Олег, давай, быстрее  собирайся/Олег, давай, собирайся быстрее.
Могу ошибаться.